# How do I move an element with transform relative to its rotation in CSS

Tags: css

Im attempting to make a clicker game with html css and javascript, and was trying to get some cursors to be animated like the ones that click for you in cookie clicker.

you will probably see what I mean when you run the project

I just want the cursors to move away from the div and then back again

here is my code:

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll("img");

images.forEach(function(e) {
  let randomval = Math.floor(Math.random() * (359 - 0 + 1))
  e.style.transform = "rotate(" + randomval + "deg)";
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clicked {
  margin: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

@keyframes clickeranim {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0, 165px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 13.1px;
  height: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: calc(250px - calc(13.1px / 2));
  transform-origin: 50% -150px;
  transform: translate(0, 150px);
  animation: clickeranim 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}

img {
  width: 13.1px;
  height: 17px;
  transform-origin: 50% -150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clicked"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/32">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/32">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/32">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/32">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/32">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/32">
</div>
```

Comment: `you will probably see what I mean when you run the project` nope, `cursor.webp` exists only in your machine. use another online image for the example/ upload it

Comment: @ATP yes I know, but you can still see the grey boxes where the images would normally be (can you?)

Comment: Are you allowed to change the markup?

Comment: @Terry what do you mean?

Comment: I afraid the only way to do it is to calculate the `x,y` distance to move using trigonometry (calculate the angle of the image with the center of the circle and the positive x axis and then `x = cos(angle) * distance; y = -sin(angle) * distance; ` check out the `atan2()` function for calculating the angle.)

Comment: @ATP alr thanks I guess.. now I gotta do math stuff weeeeee

Comment: Maybe @Terry has an idea

Comment: @ATP I FIGURED IT OUT! I just scaled the div that they're in in the animation and at the same time scaled down the image inside

Comment: clever solution! feel free answer and accept  your own question